# JSON response changing Numbers to String. How to avoid that?

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, react-native

So i'm getting some data from my mongoDB to a react native application, but when i use my function to index all collection, it doesn't keep my Numbers, turning then into String, even in the database the data is right. What am i doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
const List = require('../models/List');

module.exports = {
    async index(request, response) {
        const list = await List.find();
        console.log(list);
        return response.json(list);
    }
}
```

**Input and mongo entry:**

```
{
"name": "Jenny",
"age": 20
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
"name": "Jenny",
"age": "20"
}
```

**My model:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');    
const ListSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
});   

module.exports = mongoose.model('List', ListSchema);
```

**Update:**

I've just found the error. I haven't updated my git hub repository with the changes in the model. Now that i've updated, it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, long story short - it's working as intended. JSON, which you are logging, is not typed so of course it will be string. You can always parse it on a Front-End side though. By using `parseInt()`.

Comment: I found the error. Actually my model in my repository was unupdated and the age schema was a String. Now i've updated it and it's working fine. Even so, thanks for your answer.